# wordpress custom posts page not showing

Tags: customization, pages, templates

In Wordpress I created 2 templates :

- The first template is a custom homepage
- The second template is custom page for for post results(search by category, search by keywords)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

After that I specified them in Wordpress

[image]

The custom homepage is successfully shown when I visit the website, but when I click on a specific category, my custom posts page is not showing and I get the default page instead.

Comment: You can't use page templates for the custom posts page, besides, all of that can be done with `search.php`, hidden inputs, and URL parameters, there's no need for the page template

Answer (score 0):

For categories you would have to edit the archive.php or rather to be specific the category.php file.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

That page will give you an idea of the specificity you can go with template files.